# Access logs from grails plugins

Tags: grails, logging, grails-2.0, grails-plugin

From time to time we like everyone else like to use plugins.  Unfortunately they are not always documented all that well.  Sometimes you get lucky and find OH DEBUGGING LOG's have been included.

How do you turn on logging for the plugins?

If the plugin is packaged `org.plugin.special` and the following is our logging setup, how do we add it?

```
log4j = {
    appenders{
      rollingFile name: "myAppender", maxFileSize: 1024, file:'/development/log/eightstates.log'
      console name:'stdout', layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%c{2} %m%n'), threshold: org.apache.log4j.Level.DEBUG
    }
    debug myAppender: [
      'grails.app.controllers.come.example.eightstates',     
      'grails.app.domain.come.example.eightstates',          
      'grails.app.services.come.example.eightstates',       
      'grails.app.taglib.come.example.eightstates',       
      'grails.app.conf.come.example.eightstates',
      'grails.app.filters.come.example.eightstates',
      'grails.app.controllers.org.grails.paypal']
  }
```

Comment: To find out the name of the log, in that source code just print `log.name` then add that to your log4j setting.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason there's not a single logger for plugins is because it's dependent on the artefacts used in the plugin.  For example if the plugin uses a controller, then the logger for that will be different than the one used in the plugin's service, and so forth.  Unless the plugin offers its own hooks to enable/disable logging, I think your best bet is to enable each artefact individually (which may take a while).  I'm not 100% sure, but that's the experience I've had.

This [thread](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Resource-plugin-logging-how-to-turn-off-td3208792.html) talks about logging for the Resources plugin, if that helps at all.